# Repeating legacy option buttons within a repeating section

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently attempting to turn a form I am working on into a more dynamic one using vba in word, but I am facing two issues with the option buttons within a repeating section:

1. The code is not dynamic; when I run the code it does what I need it to but doesn't dynamically recalculate as I change my choice.
2. The option buttons do not repeat when I add a new section, and the only way for me to include them is by readding them and creating a new module specific for the new option button group.

Below is a picture of the section I am repeating and the code I am using.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhhJ9.png)

```
Private Sub Yes_Click()
    
Dim k(0 To 3) As String
    k(0) = "Select one"
    k(1) = "Pass"
    k(2) = "Fail"
    k(3) = "N/A"
    
Dim i As Long
    If Yes = True Then
        Me.Controls.Clear
        Me.Controls1.Clear
        For i = 0 To 3
            Me.Controls.AddItem k(i)
            Me.Controls1.AddItem k(i)
            Next i
    End If
            
    On Error Resume Next
            Me.Controls = "Select one"
            Me.Controls1 = "Select one"
    
    If Yes = False Then
            Me.Controls = "N/A"
            Me.Controls1 = "N/A"
    End If
    On Error Resume Next

        
End Sub
```

Is there a way to approach either issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "a repeating section" - if this refers to using a Repeating Section Content Control then you need to use content controls inside it, not legacy form controls.

Comment: Is it possible then to link content controls using macros?

Comment: If all your code does is reset the controls, that shouldn’t be necessary with content controls.

Comment: Is there a way to show you what i am working on without posting it here?